Question about bpy's matrix_world to torch3d coordinate system conversion
From the visualization results, it appears that the camera pose I converted is not accurate. It has moved backwards.  Is there have any suggestions ?QAQ
1.difference of cameras space
2 some discussion





https://pytorch3d.org/docs/cameras
